# Processing events in batches Elixir Flow

Tags: elixir

I have a flow similar to:

```
all_feed_ids
|> Flow.from_enumerable
|> Flow.map(&download_feed)    
|> Flow.flat_map(&extract_feed) # Creates many items per feed
# |> Flow.map_state(&bulk_insert_items)
|> Flow.map(&download_item)
|> Flow.flat_map(&extract_item) # Creates many sub-items per item
# |> Flow.map(&bulk_insert_subitem)
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187191/how-to-process-events-in-batches-with-elixir-flow) suggest using `Flow.map_state` but it doesn't appear to exist anymore.

As a result, I'm using the following in-place of every Flow.map_state:

```
|> Flow.partition(window: Flow.Window.count(@bulk_insert_size), stages: 1)
|> Flow.reduce(fn -> [] end, fn item, list ->
  [item | list]
end)
|> Flow.on_trigger(&bulk_insert_items)
|> Flow.partition()
```

Is this a reasonable approach or is there another function or preferred way to do this with Flow (or is this maybe even not an appropriate use case for flow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flow.map_state/2` [has not gone](https://github.com/elixir-lang/flow/commit/04b2dc05edf5dab189bc1dc74be006fd40d81878#diff-4ac32a78649ca5bdd8e0ba38b7006a1eR17). According to the [`CHANGELOG`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/flow/blob/04b2dc05edf5dab189bc1dc74be006fd40d81878/CHANGELOG.md):

> `each_state/2` and `map_state/2` — those two functions were only invoked when there was a trigger and they have now been replaced by a more explicitly named `on_trigger/2` function.

I have not reviewed nor tried your code with [`Flow.on_trigger/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html#on_trigger/2), but for me the latter worked in one om my local projects in the similar case.